# Is there a method to change a Google Calendar's access level?

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api

I have the following code to create a new calendar for a gmail contact:

```
// Create a CalenderService and authenticate
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("email@email.com", "password");

CalendarEntry calendar = new CalendarEntry
{
    Title = { Text = "Example title" },
    Summary = { Text = "Example summary" },
    TimeZone = "Europe/London",
    Hidden = false,
    Color = "#2952A3",
    Location = new Where("", "", "Location"),
};

Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
CalendarEntry createdCalendar = (CalendarEntry)myService.Insert(postUri, calendar);
```

Is there some other method or property I can use to share this calendar, in the constructor or after it's been created? I've looked through everything but nothing's jumped out, been googling and looking around this site also but have had no luck.

I've seen examples of how to set each the access level of each event try indidually, but not the whole calendar which is possible by clicking through Google's calendar settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a soution for anyone who comes across this:

```
string postUristring = string.Empty;

// note this could change in future!
string feedString = createdCalendar.Id.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
postUristring = feedString.Substring(0, feedString.Length - 28);

AclEntry entry = new AclEntry();

entry.Scope = new AclScope();
entry.Scope.Type = AclScope.SCOPE_DEFAULT;

entry.Role = new AclRole();
entry.Role = AclRole.ACL_CALENDAR_READ;

Uri aclUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"
             + postUristring + "@group.calendar.google.com" + "/acl/full");

AclEntry insertedEntry = myService.Insert(aclUri, entry);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the substring index has changed since you wrote this code.  (Or at least it's different for me now.)  The index of 63 in the code is no longer accurate.  To compensate for this, I'm currently setting that to `LastIndexOf("/") + 1`, though I imagine Google reserves the right to change the URL further at any time.